# How to have first page of PDF be used as icon preview in list view in OSX finder

Tags: macos, pdf, finder

I've got an image to clarify what I'm asking.

[Finder example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcQjW.jpg)

I want the little icon preview to be the first page of the pdf (which is the big display to the right). You can see that it works for epubs, but isn't working for pdfs. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: It's Weird it only happens in list view & column view.